# Firefox opening blank page when launching browser

Tags: ruby, eclipse, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Firefox opening blank page when launching browser using Selenium Eclipse with Ruby.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"
```

Version selenium 3.0, Firefox 49.0.2, Geckodriver latest

Comment: Try FF 49.0.1.  That's what's working for me.

Comment: @orde ,mine is 49.0.2 the latest and i am still getting the same issue.Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work when you run via command line/terminal (instead of Eclipse)?

Comment: @orde ,it still opens a blank page and skype extension in another tab when run through command line.

Comment: Without a stacktrace or more information, it's hard to say why that's happening.

Comment: @orde, what type of information do you need

Comment: Not sure.  I can't repro using `selenium-webdriver (3.0.0)`, `watir-webdriver (0.9.3)`, and `geckodriver v0.11.1`.  If it just hangs and there's no error message(s), there's unfortunately not much to go on.

Comment: @orde, This is the url of the tab that it opens up "https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34612/what-is-the-skype-extension"

Comment: Okey dokey.  Uninstall the skype extension, and see what happens.