# selenium WebDriver opens a blank tab and skype extension tab when launching FireFox browser

Tags: ruby, eclipse, selenium, capybara, skype

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "cucumber"
require "capybara"
driver=Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.for(:firefox)
driver.get"www.google.com"
```

When launching Firefox browser,webdriver opens a blank tab and tab for Skype extension.I have uninstalled Skype click to call from my system.
Version selenium 3.0, Firefox 49.0.2, Geckodriver latest.
Please help.

Comment: So you uninstalled extension from system but it's still in FF? Did you check extensions and add-ons directly in FF. Enter this to the website field in FF: `about:addons` [enter] and check it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox opening blank page when launching browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141242/firefox-opening-blank-page-when-launching-browser)